# Vsphere web client sdk could not able to load property file

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, vsphere

I am developing flex based plugin for VSphere web client using vsphere web client sdk. The view part is written in FLEX. Here I want to read some value from property file to display on view. I kept my property file at myapp/swf/src/main/flex/locale/en_US/mypropfile.properties as per vsphere web client sdk. But when I am trying to fetch the property value it is returning blank string. This is how I am trying to retrieve the value.

```
ResourceManager.getInstance().getString("mypropfile", "myPropKey")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the issue. The resources will not automatically compile. For that stop the build automatically of eclipse and compile the project using compile-resource target of build_flex.xml